# Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable, even though they are inside different cases

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, sequelize.js

Inside a controller method I have the code block below. Visual Studio Code gives the error:

> Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'count' and 'rows'

But I don't understand this because these variables are declared inside different cases and only 1 case will fire. How should I handle this?

```
switch (tab) {
    case "active":
        const { count, rows } = await User.findAndCountAll({
            where: {
                ...query,
            },
            offset,
            limit,
        });

        break;

    case "favourites":
        const { count, rows } = await User.findAndCountAll({
            where: {
                ...query,
                [Op.or]: [{ name: {[Op.like]: `%${searchText}%` }}],
            },
            offset,
            limit,
        });
        ...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The switch statement doesn't have different scopes by default, in fact if you don't use the `break` keyword at the end of a `case` the script will execute all the code in all the cases until it finds a break or the `switch` statement ends.

For example:

```
switch(1) {
    case 1:
        console.log('case 1');
    case 2:
        console.log('case 2');
}
// OUTPUT:
// case 1
// case 2
```

In this case all the cases were executed because i haven't used any `break`.

**The only scope in a switch is the switch itself** so how can you achieve your goal?

You can do it by wrapping your cases inside brackets, so it will become:

```
switch(1) {
    case 1: {
        const n = 1
        console.log('case ' + n)
        break
    }
    case 2: {
        const n = 2
        console.log('case ' + n)
        break
    }
}
// That's valid
```

If you don't want to duplicate your code just to edit the query you would probably do something like:

```
const query = { /* whatever */ }

const { count, rows } = await User.findAndCountAll({
    where: tab === 'active' ? {
        ...query,
    } : {
        ...query,
        [Op.or]: [{ name: {[Op.like]: `%${searchText}%` }}]
    },
    offset,
    limit,
})
```

By using [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) you don't even have to implement a switch and duplicate your code, you just change the query part based on your variable

Comment: Thanks for such a clear explanation! Is there also a way to solve it by not defining `count` and `rows` as constants? I tried `let count, rows;` outside the scope of the cases, but that didn't work, I think because it's `{ count, rows }`.

Comment: Yep, you're [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) them so the only alternative can be declaring them outside of the switch and then manually assign the values, in this case it's better destructuring them even if you'll have duplicate variable names. I'm editing my answer to show you another approach

Comment: I just edited my answer to show you what i would probably do to achieve your goal, hope it helps